# How to Add OpenSSL to Swift Pod Frame work

Tags: swift

I have a swift Pod currently, For to implement the security feature such as to get the organization name from the ssl certificate i need to use lib like open ssl and i want to use this open ssl as part of this pod module.
I'm using Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add `s.dependency 'OpenSSL'` to your `podspec` file.